# How can I do a backwards query-replace in emacs

Tags: emacs, text-editing

From the documentation of `query-replace`:

> [...]
>   In Transient Mark mode, if the mark is active, operate on the contents
>   of the region.  Otherwise, operate from point to the end of the
>   buffer.

What is the way to do it backwards? That is, if nothing is marked, from point to the *beginning* of the buffer? Have in mind the behavior of `isearch-forward` vs. `isearch-backward`. It might be that this kind of functionality is not available out of the box for a reason - if this is the case I would like to know what is the reason.

Answer (score 1):

There is not such a function out of the box. Unfortunately I cannot give a reason why.

As you may already know you could do the following:

1. `C-SPC`
2. `M-<`
3. `M-%`

To get the behavior you are looking for. This could be recorded into a macro and bound to a key (*cf.* http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Save-Keyboard-Macro.html)